# Getting all the records in one single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL Query to create calculated columns like this: (Simplified version of the code)

```
SELECT CUST_ID, NAME, ADDRESS,
       CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 20 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END AS COL1,
       CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 21 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END AS COL2,
       CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 22 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END AS COL3,
       CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 23 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END AS COL4,
       CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 24 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END AS COL5
FROM TABLE1
```

When I run this query this is how the report looks like. It creates multiple rows where the first condition statisfies for more that one column. How can I get unique records

```
CUSTID  NAME    ADDRESS Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
 101    Nikh    US       X       X       X       X       X
 102    Chris   Canada   Yes     X       X       X       X
 102    Chris   Canada   X       X       Yes     X       X
 103    Todd    Japan    X       X       X       Yes     X
 103    Todd    Japan    X       X       X       X       Yes
 104    Levis   China    X       X       X       X       X
 105    Jack    Germany  X       Yes     X       X       X
 105    Jack    Germany  X       X       Yes     X       X
```

Desired result:

```
CUSTID  NAME    ADDRESS Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
  101   Nikh    US       X      X       X       X        X
  102   Chris   Canada   Yes    X       Yes     X        X
  103   Todd    Japan    X      X       X       Yes      Yes
  104   Levis   China    X      X       X       X        X
  105   Jack    Germany  X      Yes     Yes     X        X
```

Comment: Can you provide desired dataset ?

Comment: You're talking about rolling up information onto each CUSTID?

Comment: @Kris You are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `MAX`:

```
SELECT  CUST_ID, 
        NAME, 
        ADDRESS,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 20 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END) AS COL1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 21 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END) AS COL2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 22 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END) AS COL3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 23 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END) AS COL4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STIP_ID = 24 AND STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END) AS COL5
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY CUST_ID, 
         NAME, 
         ADDRESS
```

Comment: Is it works ?  Can we have a MAX function from string-type parameter ?

Comment: This doesn't work. It just deletes all the records having duplicates vlaues. But this is not want I want. Please look at the desired result

Comment: @user3076028 I looked at the desired result, and this should give you that. If it doesn't, then please post a sqlfiddle with sample data instead of saying "this doesn't work". And the query doesn't delete anything from your table

Comment: Ok Sorry if I was offending. This is the case statement for the calculated column. `CASE WHEN Stips.StipulationID = 89 AND Stips.StatusID IN (39,41) THEN ('TR07_Info_Sheet' + '- ' +   `Prim.PrimaryCust) ELSE 'X' END) AS Info_Sheet` Like this I have 16 `case statements`. Is it something in my Case statement which is not giving me the desired results?

Comment: @user3076028 Well, the `CASE` *expression* that you are using is completely different than the one posted, so I wouldn't really know. It does seems like you need to change my answer into using `MIN` instead of `MAX` if you want that `TR07_Info_Sheet_...` appears instead of `X` (since `TR07_Info_Sheet_...` is less than `X`)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and replace `MAX` with `MIN` ?

Comment: @user3076028 Not unless you change your question. The answer is correct to the current requirements, the `MIN` works for your modified question that you posted in a comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57175/discussion-between-user3076028-and-lamak).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to the question as posted:**

```
SELECT [CUST_ID],[NAME],[ADDRESS],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24]
FROM TABLE1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE [STATUS] WHEN 'OPEN' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'X' END [YES OR X])
PIVOT(MAX([YES OR X]) FOR [STIP_ID] IN ([20],[21],[22],[23],[24]) ) P
```

**Solution that accommodates the new requirements:**

```
SELECT
  [CUST_ID], [NAME], [ADDRESS],
  ISNULL([20],'X'), ISNULL([21],'X'), ISNULL([22],'X'), ISNULL([23],'X'), ISNULL([24],'X')
FROM TABLE1
CROSS APPLY (CASE WHEN Stips.StipulationID = 90 AND Stips.StatusID IN (39, 41) THEN '('TR10_Pers_FS_Curr_Signed' + '- ' + Prim.PrimaryCust) ELSE 'X' END) AS TR10_Pers_FS_Curr_Signed)
PIVOT(MAX(TR10_Pers_FS_Curr_Signed) FOR [STIP_ID] IN ([20],[21],[22],[23],[24]) ) P
```

Comment: I like your answer too. But my `CASE STATEMENT` is `MIN(CASE WHEN Stips.StipulationID = 90 AND Stips.StatusID IN (39, 41) THEN '('TR10_Pers_FS_Curr_Signed' + '- ' + Prim.PrimaryCust) ELSE 'X' END) AS TR10_Pers_FS_Curr_Signed`. You observe the field where there is 'YES' is actually going to be a dynamic field in my real time code.